# How to make annotated index in LaTeX?

Tags: xetex, indexing, makeindex

I am writing a grammar textbook in LaTeX and I am trying to make annotated index of vocabulary. For example, in the main body of the document we have a sentence in Icelandic:

> Stóð þá Egill upp ok leiddi Ǫlvi útar til *duranna* ok helt á sverði sinu. En er þeir koma at *durunum* ...

Then I would like to make index over some vocabulary, for example, duranna and durunum are both conjugated form of *dyrr*, which means door, then I would like the index to be somewhat like this:

```
dyrr fem. a door or an opening
     duranna gen. 
     durunum dat.
```

I know that the nested index could be achieve by package imakeidx, but how to add notes (e.g. fem. a door or an opening) to the index?

Of course I can write something like `\index{dyrr@dyrr fem. a door or an opening}`, but that's way too stupid.

Does anyone know a better way? Thank you so much.